# How to get line color from Word [C#][Spire.Doc]

Tags: c#, ms-word, spire.doc

I have the word document which text like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFK2T.png). In my own little project I convert .doc or .docx document to .txt file via Spire.Doc and get lines by one by, then do with them some work, but now there appeared a multi-colored text and I need to get a red line as follows: Get the Word lines by one by and if the line color is not black, then add this colored line to string. I want to ignore text colored black, and get line with red text. How can I do this?

Comment: Please take a moment to read in the [help] how to effectively ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to get text in red color:

```
Document document = new Document();
document.LoadFromFile("2.docx");

Section section = document.Sections[0];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Paragraph paragraph in section.Paragraphs)
{

foreach (DocumentObject obj in paragraph.ChildObjects)
{
    if (obj is TextRange)
    {
        TextRange tr = obj as TextRange;

        if (tr.CharacterFormat.TextColor.ToArgb() == Color.Red.ToArgb())
        {
            sb.AppendLine(tr.Text);
        }
    }
}

File.WriteAllText("RedText.txt", sb.ToString());
```